# Primary Key generation MySQL Hibernate

Tags: mysql, oracle, primary-key, sequence, distributed

I have an application deployed across 2 instances.

Database: MySQL
ORM: Hibernate

However, I need to implement an Oracle sequence like behaviour. Since MySQL doesn't have any, I simply created a table with an AUTO_INCREMENT and a method to return the value from it. It's thread-safe , so its not a problem when I deploy this application on 1 server. However, I dont think this thread-safe behaviour will hold true across multiple JVMs.
What to do in this case?

Comment: MySQL will generate a new number each time a record is inserted and you routine will return the value of that number. If you only have one instance of MySQL I can't see where you would run into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to use across multiple JVMs. MySQL issues each ID once. Use `getGeneratedKeys()` on a ResultSet to retrieve the generated ID.